# Get index of rows after groupby and nlargest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, group-by

I have a large dataframe where I want to use `groupby` and `nlargest` to look for the second largest, third, fourth and fifth largest value of each group. I have over 500 groups and each group has over 1000 values. I also have other columns in the dataframe which I want to keep after applying `groupby` and `nlargest`. My dataframe looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': [1,2,3,3,4, 5,6,7,7,8],
    'a': [4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 20, 10, 40, 50, 30],
    'b': [20, 10, 40, 50, 30, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2],
    'c': [25, 20, 5, 15, 10, 25, 20, 5, 15, 10]
})
```

To look for second, third, fourth largest and so on of each group for column `a` I use

```
secondlargest = df.groupby(['group'], as_index=False)['a'].apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(2).min())
```

which returns

```
   group   a
0      1   4
1      2   5
2      3   1
3      4   2
4      5  20
5      6  10
6      7  40
7      8  30
```

I need columns `b` and `c` present in this resulting dataframe. I use the following to subset the original dataframe but it returns an empty dataframe. How should I modify the code?

```
secondsubset = df[df.groupby(['group'])['a'].apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(2).min())]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, you should be able to just drop `as_index=False`, use [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) instead of `min`, pass the result to `df.loc`:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('group')['a'].apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(2).idxmin())]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can uses agg lambda. It is neater

```
df.groupby('group').agg(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(2).min())
```

Comment: thanks for answering, I tried your solution but it didn't return all columns in the dataframe.